# asp.net core application redundancy

Tags: azure, redundancy

I need that an **asp.net core application** in azure to have **redundancy**. If one application fails another, take over your tasks online. I didn't find anything that I can use as a guide. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Explain better your question, are u using VMs? App Service? Building an API, Web Application? Have you a SLA requirement? Redundancy is normally used for storage business continuity, RTO, RPO.. Are you trying to achieve HA instead?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. For now I plan to mount it in Azure with virtual machines. I plan for my application to have high availability where if one server fails, another takes over its tasks in a transparent way for the users.

Comment: One important thing you will need to do is make your tasks idempotent so that if a VM dies in between processing a task, when other VM picks up that task it should not fail for any subtasks that have already been completed.

Answer (score 1):

Azure VMs HA options:

1. Use Availability Set: An [availability set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/availability-set-overview) is a logical grouping of VMs that allows Azure to understand how your application is built to provide for redundancy and availability. (SLA 99,95%)
2. Scale Sets: Azure virtual machine [scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview?context=/azure/virtual-machines/context/context) let you create and manage a group of load balanced VMs. The number of VM instances can automatically increase or decrease in response to demand or a defined schedule. Scale sets provide high availability to your applications, and allow you to centrally manage, configure, and update many VMs.

**Load Balancing**

Also follow this decission tree as starting point to choose whatever feats your needs.

[image]